# Remove thumb and set progressTint for disabled seekbar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, seekbar

The default seekbar behavior on disable is to keep the `thumb` visual and remove the progress color. I would like to flip this and instead remove the thumb and keep the progress color (though I'll want to change the color value).

I thought that I could just use ColorStateLists for the `thumbTint` and the `progressTint` but that didn't work. Making the thumb transparent left a weird gap in the bar, and the disabled color of the `progressTint` is always ignored.

Current Enabled State:

[image: Current Enabled State]

Current Disabled State:

[image: Current Disabled State]

Desired Disabled State:

[image: Desired Disabled State]

Layout:

```
<SeekBar
    style="@style/Zero.Seekbar.Green"
    android:id="@+id/sb_range"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/tv_range_value"
    android:progress="140"
    android:max="200"
    android:enabled="@{viewModel.rangeEnabled}"
    />
```

styles.xml:

```
<!-- SeekBar-->
<style name="Zero.Seekbar" parent="Zero">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/gutter_width</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/gutter_width</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/zero_orange</item>
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/zero_gray_header</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/slider_thumb_ride_mode</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">parent</item>
</style>

<style name="Zero.Seekbar.Green" parent="Zero.Seekbar">
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/color_seekbar_green</item>
    <item name="android:thumbTint">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

color_seekbar_green.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:color="@color/zero_green" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:color="@color/zero_yellow" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ProgressBar instead